# What to send Yodlee endpoint EnableAccountForAggregation

Tags: yodlee

We are trying to use Yodlee's REST matching service and during the flow they have given us one of the endpoints is /jsonsdk/ItemAccountManagement/enableAccountForAggregation. In their java docs it says to send them the userContext, itemAccountId, and itemDetails.

For userContext we are sending the cobSessionToken and the userSessionToken. 
For itemAccountId we are sending the itemAccountId passed in from the addTransferAccount call
For itemDetails we are trying to send the form with the values that we received from the getLoginFormForContentService call.

Our problem is we are not sure how it should be formatted or what all we need to send.

Below is an example of what we have sent in itemDetails (we are using node to connect to their API hence we are building the form and then sending it across)

Any help on the format or example code of what to send and how to format it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
'itemDetails.shareCredentialsWithinSite': true,
'itemDetails.startRefreshOnAddition': true,
'itemDetails.credentialFields.enclosedType':'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].displayName': 'Username',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].helpText': '150862',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].maxlength': 40,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].name': 'LOGIN',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].size': 20,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].value': testlogin,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier': 'LOGIN',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].valueMask': 'LOGIN_FIELD',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].isEditable': true,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].isEscaped': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].isOptional': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].isMFA': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[0].isOptionalMFA': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].displayName': 'Password',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName': 'IF_PASSWORD',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].helpText': '150863',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].maxlength': 40,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].name': 'PASSWORD',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].size': 20,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].value': testPassword,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier': 'PASSWORD',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].valueMask': 'LOGIN_FIELD',
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].isEditable': true,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].isEscaped': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].isOptional': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].isMFA': false,
'itemDetails.credentialFields[1].isOptionalMFA': false
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same as other calls (like `addItemForContentService1`, but if it is, you don't need the "itemDetails." prefix for the credentialFields properties. You also really only need to set the `name` and `value` items in the response (for each field). I found the rest to only cause issues. HTH.

Comment: I noticed that you're using node, and I'm looking at a project to do the same - is there an NPM module or some sample client code that you used (or have created)?

Answer (score 1):

Sending these parameters should work

`'cobSessionToken' : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

'userSessionToken' : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

'ItemAccountId' : 1231231

'ItemDetails.shareCredentialsWithinSite': true,
'ItemDetails.startRefreshOnAddition': true,

'ItemDetails.contentServiceId': 14748
'ItemDetails.credentialFields.enclosedType':'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[0].displayName': 'Username',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[0].name': 'LOGIN',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[0].value': testlogin,
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier': 'LOGIN',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[0].valueMask': 'LOGIN_FIELD',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName': 'IF_LOGIN',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].displayName': 'Password',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName': 'IF_PASSWORD',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].name': 'PASSWORD',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].value': testPassword,
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier': 'PASSWORD',
'ItemDetails.credentialFields[1].valueMask': 'LOGIN_FIELD',`
,

Comment: Right now our VPN is not allowing me to try this out but as soon as I do I will let you know if it worked. Thank you!

Comment: We got back a error of 

{ errorOccured: 'true',
  exceptionType: 'com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException',
  refrenceCode: '_3695546d-cf2e-419c-a0f2-48f3f3609afc',
  message: 'Null argument specified for: ItemDetails' }

Comment: This error comes if the credentialFields List is null or any value in the List is null. I will try to do more debugging on this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks let me know what you find!